# Datatable sorting PHP, paging button missing

Tags: javascript, php, sorting, datatable

I was trying so hard to solve this problem, but it really make my mind explode.

Everything displays nicely including the paging,listing and the date are sorted by asc (Default)

After I added in Java script(make it sort by desc)
This is javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

jQuery(document).ready(function(j)
{
        $('#example').dataTable({
        'aaSorting': [[0,'desc']]      //Sorts 1st column asc
        })
});
</script>
```

Data listing sorted, everything is still cool, but the paging buttons are missing, left "Showing X to X of X entries"

Please Help!

Here is my script
added this at the bottom of the script
import datatable js

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/demo/demo-datatables.js'></script>
```

Table script:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="stdtable stdtablecb datatables" id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>'.__("Date").'</th>
                    <th>'.__("Description").'</th>
                    <th>'.__("Credit").'</th>
                    <th>'.__("Debit").'</th>
                    <th>'.__("Balance").'</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
            '.$his_row.'
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

////////////////////////////

```
for($i=0;$i<$this_page_total;$i++){

 $p=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);

 $his_row.='
    <tr class="'.($k==0?'even':'odd').'">
        <td class="center">'.$p["cdate"].'</td>
        <td>'.$p["descr"].'</td>
        <td>'.number_format(in_array($p['type'],array('c','credit'))? $p['amount'] : 0, 2).'</td>
        <td>'.number_format(!in_array($p['type'],array('c','credit'))? $p['amount'] : 0, 2).'</td>
        <td class="center">'.nl2br($p["bal"]).'</td>
    </tr>
 ';

 $k=1-$k;

}
```

Here are the link for my datatables (Sorry for I cant post any image here due to low reputation)
**This is the datatable that sort by default(ASC)**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fj8lqj766o4vgeb/Screenshot%202015-03-27%2018.33.52.png?dl=0

**This is the datatable that after insert javascript sort by desc**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pphc70cp7ntyty8/Screenshot%202015-03-27%2018.34.34.png?dl=0

Comment: what does the console say (hit f12)

Comment: Hi, console says nth. no error no warning at all

Comment: now gt error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'TableTools' of undefined

Comment: can you show mor of you htm/javascript

Comment: Where do you load tabletools? Perhaps this [1] can help [1] http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21190/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-tabletools-of-undefined

Comment: it automatically load it when it found my table class="stdtable stdtablecb datatables" and id="example", it auto generate the tabletools

Comment: I mean twhrer do you load the JS file "dataTables.tableTools.[min].js"

Comment: I did not use that in my script. But anyway, I just added it in, and I gt an error about getting 1.9 or newer version of tabletools, I went to download latest version and insert it into the script, it still pop up and says that same thing.

Comment: Instead of downloading the files try loading them directly from the site http://datatables.net/download/

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I was download from there. now everything is okay, paging are show but left 2 datatable alerts, its about Cannot reinitialise datatable and invalid JSON response. I am trying to fix it.